# Can anyone address me 3 or more websites based on salesforce?

Tags: site.com

Can anyone address me 3 or more websites based on salesforce?
I want to have an idea about the front end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at some of the websites built using force.com sites here

http://developer.force.com/sitesgallery

Regarding front end with visualforce as the container you can use any front end technology like react or Angular to build responsive websites.